# Property ' name ' does not exist on type' [ ] '

Tags: angular, typescript

Im declaring the array IProducts within the property products Like its shown below.. But what is annoying me that they are not recongnizing that productName is declared ..Please I need a help

*product-list.component.ts*

```
filteredProducts: IProduct[];
products : IProduct[] = [{
        "productId": 2 ,
        "productName": "Garden Cart" ,
        "productCode": "GDN-0023" ,
        "releaseDate": "March 18,2018",
        "description":  " 15 gallon capacity rolling",
        "price" :   32.99,
        "starRating": 4.2,
        "imageUrl" : "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/sgv_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png",

    },
    {

        "productId": 5 ,
        "productName": "Hammer" ,
        "productCode": "TBX-0048" ,
        "releaseDate": "May 21,2016",
        "description":  " Curved claw steel Hammer",
        "price" :   8.9,
        "starRating": 4.8,
        "imageUrl" : "http://openclipart.org/image",


    }
] ;

constructor() {

  this.filteredProducts = this.products;
  this.listFilter = 'cart';
}

performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[]{
    filterBy =filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
        this.products.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
}
```

The terminal generates the following error : "src/app/products/product-list.component.ts(131,27): error TS2339: Property 'productName' does not exist on type 'IProduct[]'."

Comment: Looks right, I guess your array doesn't have a property called productName but your single product inside the array probably has ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go on a limb from what you are showing and say that `this.products` is an array of `IProduct`.

You are trying to access the property `productName` of an array, you need to specify which element of the array you want to access. Luckily you are already having access to a element in your filter function, so you can do

```
return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have issues in your syntax
here is how to resolve this:

```
performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[]{
        filterBy =filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1
    )}
```

Basically it iterates through the array where product: IProduct is an element of the array

Answer (score 0):

`IProduct` must be a modal and `productName` must be a property in it.

or just use `products: any` instead of `products: IProduct[]`